# C# DLL from C++ Code - p/invoke - Change values

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio-2015, pinvoke

I've got a C# DLL using a lot of "Common" DLLs. Now I'd like to call some of these functions/methods from a C++ Program.

In the C# Code I have a structure like this

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Test
{
    public string MyTestString;
    public int MyInteger;
}
```

and a delegate

```cs
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void CallBackDelegate(Test t);
```

which is being used in a class having the "callback".

```
_delegate = new CallBackDelegate(this.CallBack);

public void CallBack(Test t)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Received string: {t.MyTestString}");
}
```

In the C++/CLI code I've got the "same" structure too. (C++ Projects are Unicode)

```cpp
struct Test
{
    char *MyTestString;
    int MyInteger;
};
```

and I export the used function to access the C# code.

```
__declspec(dllexport) void bridge(Test t);
```

In the function I instantiate a object^ of the C# class and take the delegate as `IntPtr`.

```
IntPtr ptr = System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(csharp->GetDelegate());
```

After that I call the function and pass a object of the structure as parameter.

```
//typedef void(*NativeToManaged)(Test t);
NativeToManaged funcPtr = static_cast<NativeToManaged>(ptr.ToPointer());
funcPtr(t);
```

In the unmanaged code I allocate memory for the char* and copy/assign a string. `"What is happening"` as example. (Using the C++/CLI header)

---

**Now to the problem:**

I receive the structure in the C# code correctly, though trying to set a string or modify the integer on C# side does not change anything on C++ side - I assume the structure is just being copied, though I do not know how I'd pass a reference to the C# code. (Possibly as pointer or by ref ?)

As this is my first time doing this, does anyone by chance know where the issue lies ? The C# code should correctly receive the string[s] and other values and be able to modify them. I've so far not been able to find a solution for this on Google and here.

Comment: This is C++/CLI rather than C++. Stop using p/invoke and add a reference to the C# assembly.

Comment: You are passing a struct by value, that makes it *impossible* to update the native struct.  The argument must be declared `[In, Out] ref Test t`.  And your native code must be changed accordingly, using `Test* t`.  The string is a big memory management problem, you can declare it IntPtr but that makes it very easy to corrupt and leak memory.  Only safe way is to declare it BSTR in your native code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Could you explain a little further, how this would work with unmanaged C++ code ? As you can see in my question, this is an example, I have unmanaged C++ code and want to call into a C# DLL. If I could add a reference to the unmanaged code I'd do it.

Comment: @HansPassant I've changed the delegates signature taking `[In, Out] ref Test t` as parameter and changed the structure's string to `BSTR`. Thank you for that. Though I'm still not sure how I pass the struct properly to the C# code. Currently I have a variable of `Test` declared and pass this to the C# delegate as `Test*` (&t). Is this correct ? It appears that `a heap has been corrupted` everytime I try to run it.

Comment: You have C#, C++/CLI and C++? I thought it was just C# and C++/CLI.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The C++/CLI is just a wrapper to call the C# code. I'm unable to use anything Com related in the unmanaged C++ code.

Comment: You could omit the C++/CLI layer and use UnmanagedExports. But as for allowing modification of the struct, it's `ref Test test` on the C# side and `Test& test` on the C++ side. Or perhaps `Test* test` if you prefer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Apparently it works if I don't set the string value previously in the unmanaged C++ code (leave it 0) and assign a string on the C# side. But if I assign a string on the C++ side too, it says that a heap has been corrupted. Example as in question: `t.MyTestString = SysAllocString(L"What is happening");` Any idea what might cause that ?

Comment: You have not marshalled the string as `BStr`. I guess your code has changed though now from what is in the question. Probably time for a new question. Now that you know how to pass structs by ref.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's all I was missing, thank you, it works fine now.